# Is it correct to say "There's many a ..."?

Tags: grammaticality, there-is, many-a

Today on [GUARDIAN life&style](http://www.guardian.co.uk/lifeandstyle) is this teaser:

> There's many a garden outbuilding crying out for a makeover.

I'm wondering if this sentence is correct. I think there either should *many* be deleted (i.e. *There is a garden outbuilding*) or *is* should be *are*, the *a* should be dropped and an s should be added to verb *outbuilding* (i.e. *There are many garden outbuildings*).

Or does the sentence make sense in any way I don't recognize?

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/many_a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. It's a phrase that is combined with a singular noun. From http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/many:

> **many a**: a large number of
>
> > *Many a good man has been destroyed by booze*
> >      *John and I have talked about it many a time*

Comment: It's not commonly used anymore, especially in everyday speech, but ash's answer is correct.

Comment: @aaamos: I use it!

Comment: @BarrieEngland: As do I... but that doesn't make it common ;-)

Comment: Just that I understand it correctly: *A large number of* refers to - let' say - 10 things but they are *wrapped into one packet* and we just refer to this one wrap?

Comment: @Em1: Yes, as ash said, it's used with a singular noun, irrespective of the actual quantity.

Comment: @Em1: In that particular case, we'd be more likely to say 'one packet' than 'one wrap'.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @aaamos. I just wasn't sure that I got it right because in my mother tongue we still take the plural for that case (but I recognize right now that in case of *abundance of* we also change to singular).

Comment: A proverb using this construction is: Many a pickle makes a mickle.

Comment: @Shyam Google offers me *Many a little makes a mickle* or *Many a mickle makes a muckle* but not the way you mentioned it. Is your variation a parody of this proverb?

Comment: @Em1: Just one of the many variants. This one is in the OED.

Comment: @aaamos: [an NGram comparison of 'many a' and 'not commonly used'] (http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=many+a%2C+not+commonly+used&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) shows that the first is much more common than the second (but there is a point that it is losing popularity). (this just shows that 'many a' is not particularly uncommon, though I agree that I feel it is not common at least in speech).